# Prompt not showing up after a sequence of typing animations in jQuery Terminal

Tags: jquery-terminal

```js
 eth_atr_d9: function() {
                this.echo('Entering... ', { typing: true, delay: 10 });
                this.echo('Text1', { typing: true, delay: 30 });
                this.echo('Text2', { typing: true, delay: 30 });
```

On entering this command 'eth_atr_d9', the text to be echoed is printed normally but the ">" does not come, still it allows to enter another command which too works perfectly fine.

I tried changing the length of the text but the problem is occurring with only this command rest 6 commands work normally. I tried it locally and on codepen.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that animation is asynchronous. You can't call the next animation before the first finishes. Otherwise, you will end up with an odd state.

try something like this:

```js
const commands = {
   eth_atr_d9: async function() {
       await this.echo('Entering... ', { typing: true, delay: 10 }); 
       await this.echo('Text1', { typing: true, delay: 30 });
       await this.echo('Text2', { typing: true, delay: 30 });
   }
};
```

Here is a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/LYJmxzx?editors=0010).

I've added this to [Wiki](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/wiki/Typing-Animation#sequence-of-animations).